# Unable to Wrap the Array of Json Object in apex using wrapper class

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class

I am unable to wrap the Array of JSON object in apex using wrapper

**JSON**

```
    {
    "personInfo": {
        "firstName": "Sudhanshu",
        "lastName": "Singhs"
    },
    "contactInfo": [
        {
            "mobile": "1231",
            "email": "s@email.com"
        },
        {
            "mobile": "1231",
            "email": "s@email.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Wrapper Class**

```
public class SampleWrapper {
    public PersonInformation personInfo;
    public List<ContactInformation> contactInfo;
        
    public class ContactInformation{
        public String mobile;
        public String email;
    }
    public class PersonInformation{
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
    }
    
}
```

**My Class**

```
public class SampleWrapperValidate {
    public static void validate(){
        Conversion_Service_Configuration__mdt   con = Conversion_Service_Configuration__mdt.getInstance('sampleConfig');
        String json = con.JSON_Configuration__c;
        
        SampleWrapper wrp =  (SampleWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(json, SampleWrapper.class);
        System.debug(wrp.contactInfo);
        
    }
}
```

***ERROR: System.JSONException: Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries at [line:13, column:267]***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in my org. just skip the custom metadata part and it works fine. Make sure that the JSON coming from the custom metadata is valid.

Wrapper Class:

```
public class SampleWrapper {
    public PersonInformation personInfo;
    public List<ContactInformation> contactInfo;
    
    public class ContactInformation{
        public String mobile;
        public String email;
    }
    public class PersonInformation{
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
    }    
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public class SampleWrapperValidate {
    public static void validate(){
        //Conversion_Service_Configuration__mdt   con = Conversion_Service_Configuration__mdt.getInstance('sampleConfig');
        //String json = con.JSON_Configuration__c;
        
        String jsonData = '{"personInfo":{"firstName":"Sudhanshu","lastName":"Singhs"},"contactInfo":[{"mobile":"1231","email":"s@email.com"},{"mobile":"1231","email":"s@email.com"}]}';
        
        SampleWrapper wrp =  (SampleWrapper) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonData, SampleWrapper.class);
        System.debug(wrp.contactInfo);
        
    }
}
```

Click on Debug in the developer console, click on the **Open Execute Anonymous Window** and run the below code.

```
SampleWrapperValidate.validate();
```

Output::

[image]